# RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, javascript, html

In case we are registering a java script inside the Server side code using RegisterStartupScript. would the script be added to the page each time the RegisterStartupScript is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, So if you call `RegisterStartupScript()` from a button click postback event, it will be included in the page for that post back but it will not be included for other postbacks. If you call `RegisterStartupScript()` in `Page_Load` if will be included everytime (which might be pointless as you can just statically include the script to the page).

Answer (score 1):

RegisterStartupScript will register the script to be added at the top of DOM. Incase you are calling it multiple times in the same page life cycle, you can use the `key` parameter to prevent duplicacy of the script on the page.

Comment: yes i am currently avoiding duplicates with different keys but my basic concern is that sometimes that controls (Drop Down for example) which are manipulated using client events are getting so slow to select from.